# radare2 - radare2 doesn't display string value

Tags: radare2

I have some rare cases with radare2.

when I try to display all string using **"iz"** it does the job.

[image]

but when I do **"pdf"** or **"pd"** I can't see actual value of string:

[image]

I see *int puts(const char *s)* **instead of "incorrect password" or "Access granted!"**

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug in radare2.
The comment that you see in red is merely the imported function prototype. In both cases seen in the picture, the parameter to `puts` is pushed through `eax` whereas it is loaded from a memory location based on `ebx`. radare2 does not emulate the code [unless told], so it cannot display the actual string being pointed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can you tell me how can I force radare2 to display actual string?

Comment: You need to use ESIL emulation for that. Load the binary into radare2 and analyze with `aa` (or `aaa` if binary is not too complex). Then disassemble the function (e.g. `main`) while setting `emu.str` temporarily: `pdf @e:emu.str=true @ main`